# Laravel Passport new access token generated on login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I've gotten Laravel 5.6 set up with Passport and working with the Implicit grant.

The only thing I don't understand is, every time I hit `/oauth/authorize`, a new access token is generated in the database. If there is no existing token, it will prompt the user to authorise the request and then create a new access token that expires in 1 year.

If a token already exists and is valid (e.g. user already authorised the request before), it logs the user in directly but also creates a new access token (leaving n+ tokens available instead of invalidating the previous tokens).

This means that my users will see duplicates in their 'authorised applications' screen, which doesn't look right.

Is this normal? Should I be doing something more when logging out instead of just deleting the token locally?